# Coodinates generate and molecule functionnalization

Tags: python, chemistry, rdkit, molecule, xyz

I need help please. Can someone guide me on how to generate the xyz coordinates of all functionalized Azulene molecules knowing the positions of the functional groups (1,3,9) and the functional groups (C(CN)2, COCH3, Br)?

I search the answer on the rdkit documentation but nothing. As I'm novice, I just want a method to guide me